# Failed to determine peer security context: Protocol not available

Tags: java, linux, unix, process, rhel7

I have a service named 'dataService' when i am starting/stopping/restarting this service from the CLI it works absolutely fine but when i execute the service from my java code it gives the errorStream - "Failed to determine peer security context: Protocol not available".

Java Code :-

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.getCommandLine());
            BufferedReader datainput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = datainput.readLine()) != null){
                buf.append(inputLine).append("\n");
            }

            //Wait for Process to complete.
            int returnCode = process.waitFor();
            process.destroy();
```

This issue is only happening in RHEL7.X and CentOS 7.X. Any help will be highly appreciated.